# CASE WHEN to add commas only when there is a value

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, case

I have a multiple fields that needs to be put into a string only when there is something in the field and on top of that I don't want the commas between fields if they are null.  I tried using case when but am clearly doing something wrong and would appreciate some help with the following:

```
USE newCityCollection

UPDATE PropertyInformationDump
SET    RegistryAdd = (CASE
                        WHEN b.OCAREOF IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.OCAREOF, '')
                        ELSE b.OCAREOF + ' ,'
                      END) + (CASE
                                WHEN b.O1STADD IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.O1STADD, '')
                                ELSE b.O1STADD + ' ,'
                              END) + (CASE
                                        WHEN b.O2NDADD IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.O2NDADD, '')
                                        ELSE b.O2NDADD + ' ,'
                                      END) + (CASE
                                                WHEN b.OSTNAME IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.OSTNAME, '')
                                                ELSE b.OSTNAME + ' ,'
                                              END) + (CASE
                                                        WHEN b.OCITYST IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.OCITYST, '')
                                                        ELSE b.OCITYST + ' ,'
                                                      END) + (CASE
                                                                WHEN b.OZIP IS NULL THEN Isnull(b.OZIP, '')
                                                                ELSE b.OZIP + ' ,'
                                                              END)
FROM   dbo.vw_BRT b
WHERE  BRTNumber = b.PARCEL
```

When I execute that on a field I get nada and am not sure why which is likely a fundemental misunderstanding of how `CASE` works. I did make sure those fields were actually null and not empty so that is not the problem.

Comment: one of those litle monsters :D this query is ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following: when you join strings together in SQL, and one of them is `null`, the result is `null`(*). So, if you add the comma *before* eliminating `null`s, it's a tad easier:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.OCAREOF + ' ,','') + COALESCE(b.O1STADD + ' ,','') + ...
```

No `CASE` needed here.

`COALESCE` is similar to `ISNULL` and would usually be recommended except for a few odd situations - for one, it's part of standard SQL (useful if you ever have to work against other RDBMSes), for another it can accept *multiple* arguments and returns the first non-`NULL` one. For a third, it uses the most appropriate data type for the result considering the types of each expression - `ISNULL` always tries to convert the second argument to the type of the first)

---

(I'm also not sure what you we're doing in your `CASE` expressions - you'd already established that, e.g. `OCAREOF` was null - there was no need to then use an `ISNULL` expression to obtain `''`)

---

(*) As Conrad points out, on SQL Server this does depend on `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` being `ON`, but it is by default and [it *really* should be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx):

> In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always be `ON` and any applications that explicitly set the option to `OFF` will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: @ConradFrix - added as a footnote.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I tried that with IsNull and it failed so I tried other ways.  Will use Coalesce in the future!  Great info!

Comment: Nice. This can handle empty string fields as well using `nullif`:
 `coalesce(', ' + nullif(O1STADD,''))`

Answer (score 0):

The solution still adds a comma even if no values are following. Since SQL Server 2017 you can use `CONCAT_WS` (= concat with separator) like so:

```
UPDATE PropertyInformationDump
   SET RegistryAdd = concat_ws(' ,', b.OCAREOF, b.O1STADD, b.O2NDADD, ...)
```